# Jenkins launches a Perl script that has ANT in it, but ANT is unable to read a .properties file

Tags: perl, ant, jenkins

Previously I had Jenkins launching a perl build script that at some point during the script would open up a .bat file that launched our ANT jobs. I'm trying to consolidate and get rid of the .bat files and launch ANT straight from the perl script. I have been able to successfully do this, but the problem is the .properties file that the ANT script looked at for it's variables is no longer being imported correctly as it was when the .bat file launched the ANT script.

Currently I'm just called an "Exec("ant -buildfile C:\project\buildfile.xml") and that fires off the ant, but it comes back with an error, "Cannot find ${script.dir}/barbuildfile.xml". The "script.dir" is being defined in a .properties file that is located in the same directory as the build files. This works perfectly when it's launched by the .bat file, but it fails whenever it's called through Perl. Any reason why? Or better yet, how to fix it?

I have also tried forcing it to load the properties file by launching. "Exec("ant -buildfile C:\project\buildfile.xml -Dpropertyfile=C:\project\build.properties")" and receive the same error.

Edit:
This is the.bat file

```
set project.name=%1

set environment=%2

set version.tag=%3

set build.list=%4

set JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\IBM\jdk

set ANT_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\IBM\IMShared\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145

set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\bin


CALL ant -buildfile C:\scripts\build_service.xml
```

Perl Script:

```
system("set project.name=$project");
system("set environment=$environment");
system("set version.tag=$version");
system("set build.list=$service");
system("set JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\IBM\jdk");
system("set ANT_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\IBM\IMShared\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145");
system("set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\bin");
exec("CALL ant -buildfile C:\\scripts\\build_service.xml
```

Comment: Why do you call ant from the perl script? Jenkins has a [Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin), which adds Ant support. If your script generates or modifies the buildfile you should just set up two actions in your config. One for the Perl script and after that one for the Ant build.

Comment: This might be the best route to take. I'm trying to consolidate and have everything in the same spot, but if I can't get it to work properly in PERL this is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

First, please consider calling ANT directly from Jenkins
via the dedicated [ANT Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin), as mentioned by [Demnogonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912500/demnogonis).

Second, the way it is currently written, each `system(...)` command runs in its own CMD window,
without any knowledge of the other *system* commands that ran before it
(those previous commands already went out-of-scope), for example -

- Changes made in 'my_setup.bat' are NOT available to 'ANT':

  ```
  exec("my_setup.bat");
  # at this point, 'my_setup.bat' is forgotten
  exec("ANT ...");
  ```

  or

  ```
  system("my_setup.bat");
  # at this point, 'my_setup.bat' is forgotten
  exec("ANT ...");
  ```
- Setup in 'run_my_ant.bat' are known to ANT, assuming ANT is called from within the BAT-file,
  after the changes were made:

  ```
  exec("run_my_ant.bat");
  ```

To overcome this, use the `%ENV` hash to set variable in your environment,
in a way that will make them available for other commands in your script:

```
$ENV{'project.name'} = $project;
$ENV{'environment'}  = $environment;
$ENV{'version.tag'}  = $version;
$ENV{'build.list'}   = $service;
$ENV{'JAVA_HOME'}    = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\IBM\\jdk";
$ENV{'ANT_HOME'}     = "C:\\ProgramFiles\\IBM\\IMShared\\plugins\\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145";
$ENV{'PATH'}         = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\IMShared\\plugins\\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\\bin";
exec("CALL ant -buildfile C:\\scripts\\build_service.xml ...");
```

See also here:

- [How do I set an environment-variable in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747796/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-perl)
- [Can we set a variable used in perl script as environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406152/can-we-set-a-variable-used-in-perl-script-as-environment-variable)

Good Luck!

Comment: Oops, I typed it wrong in my original post, I am using the double backslashes like you mentioned. For some reason it's really not getting any of the values populated in that property file. I verified that the path is correct as well.

I also went through and made sure that everything that is being set in the .bat file is currently being set in the perl script.

Comment: in the .bat file it was doing
*code* Call C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\7.0\bin\mqsiprofile.cmd
Set project.name=%1
Set environemnt=%2
Set version.tag=$3
Call ant -buildfile  c:\path\build.xml


What I can in my perl script system("call C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\MQSI\\7.0\\bin\\mqsiprofile.cmd");
system("set project.name=$project");
system("set environment=$environemnt");
system("set version.tag=$version");
exec("ant -buildfile C:\\path\\build.xml");

Comment: Yes, you need to have all 4 commands in the same script, and call them with a single 'system' command. Can confirm this by adding system("SET"); after each 'system' command you currently have - it will show that the setup actions are not registered.

Comment: So I have all 4 commands in the same script and it doesn't appear to be fixing anything. What am I doing wrong again? I think I'm confusing myself, LOL!

Comment: Went ahead and added the .bat file and what's done in the perl

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes sense. Is there a way that I can lump them all together while still maintaining one PERL script

Comment: I think you can use `$ENV{project.name}=$project;` instead of `system("set project.name=$project");` but not sure it will be available for your ANT - need to check.

Comment: OK, the above should work - have edited my answer with a code-example to match your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18968/discussion-between-gonen-and-heuristic)

Comment: It appears the environment settings and stuff are working, but I am running in to a problem. The ant build looks at a properties file and the values from this properties file is not being properly populated. Only way I'm able to get the build script to continue is by defining everything that's in the properties files, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: This sounds like a problem related to ANT and not to Perl - maybe ANT does not see the properties file? Make sure the path is correct - can try to run `exec("dir path-to-properties-file");` and see if it finds it.

Comment: It was able to find the property file properly. I tried to switch this over to the chat thing, but for some reason that portion of this website is blocked